# Desktop notification should popup when my website is closed

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I have the following scenario, desktop notification is enabled when my website is open. Samething I wanted to do even my website is closed. I am using RESTAPI to trigger the notification from backend. So how do we display notification if website is closed.

```
   <a href="#" id="dnperm">Request Permission</a>
                <a href="#" id="dntrigger">Trigger</a>
            <script>
            var dnperm = document.getElementById('dnperm');
            var dntrigger = document.getElementById('dntrigger');

                dnperm.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            if(!window.Notification){
                alert('Sorry, Notifications are not supported');
            }
                    else{
                        Notification.requestPermission(function(p){
    console.log(p);                 });
                    }

                });
                //simulate an event             


     dntrigger.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var notify;
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(Notification.permission);

            if(Notification.permission === 'default'){
                alert('please allow notification'); }
            else{
                notify = new Notification('new message for you Nicoleta' ,{
                body:'how are you ',
                icon:'assets/images/logo.jpg'
            });
                notify.onlclick = function(){
        window.location = 

    '?message='+this.tag;       }
            }
        }); 


            </script>
```

Comment: Do you have a service worker running in the background?  Is your site sitting behind an SSL?

Comment: no , I really dont have idea about to run the service worker at background. could you suggest me .

Comment: Have a go at [this](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#0).  It will teach you how to create your first PWA

Comment: @oninross sure I will do it